# XML to CSV code formatting

Tags: xml, csv

I am not skilled xml developer and I have managed to structure my xsl code just about right. I am traversing the nodes and getting the data from a child node correctly but not getting the desired result. This is my xml and it can also be found here http://xsltransform.net/gWmuiKs/4:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Body>
       <WorkDayInfo>
           <Activities>test1</Activities>
           <Date>12-01-12</Date>
           <Entries>
              <HourEntry>
                 <CaseGUID>3fee9c7</CaseGUID>
                 <GUID>kfsdsdlf</GUID>
                 <InvoiceGUID>a2d169</InvoiceGUID>
                 <UserGUID>4b4328</UserGUID>
                 <WorkTypeGUID>31566</WorkTypeGUID>
              </HourEntry>  
              <HourEntry>
                 <CaseGUID>1111</CaseGUID>
                 <GUID>2222</GUID>
                 <InvoiceGUID>3333</InvoiceGUID>
                 <UserGUID>4444</UserGUID>
                 <WorkTypeGUID>5555</WorkTypeGUID>
              </HourEntry> 
           </Entries>
           <ExpectedHours>9</ExpectedHours>
           <TotalHours>10</TotalHours>
    </WorkDayInfo>
    <WorkDayInfo>
        <Activities>test2</Activities>
        <Date>13-01-09</Date>
           <Entries>
             <HourEntry>
                 <CaseGUID>3fee9c79c</CaseGUID>
                 <GUID>kfsdsdl</GUID>
                 <InvoiceGUID>a2d169c</InvoiceGUID>
                 <UserGUID>4b43281</UserGUID>
                 <WorkTypeGUID>31566f</WorkTypeGUID>
             </HourEntry>
                <HourEntry>
                 <CaseGUID>3fee9c7s</CaseGUID>
                 <GUID>kfsdsd4</GUID>
                 <InvoiceGUID>a2d16s</InvoiceGUID>
                 <UserGUID>4b43281ab</UserGUID>
                 <WorkTypeGUID>31566s6</WorkTypeGUID>
             </HourEntry>
           </Entries>
        <ExpectedHours>3</ExpectedHours>
        <TotalHours>5</TotalHours>   
    </WorkDayInfo>
    <WorkDayInfo>
        <Activities>test3</Activities>
        <Date>13-01-09</Date>
           <Entries>         
           </Entries>
        <ExpectedHours>1</ExpectedHours>
        <TotalHours>4</TotalHours>
    </WorkDayInfo>      
    <WorkDayInfo>
        <Activities>test4</Activities>
        <Date>13-01-09</Date>
           <Entries>
             <HourEntry>
                 <CaseGUID>3fee9c790</CaseGUID>
                 <GUID>kfsdsdlfk</GUID>
                 <InvoiceGUID>a2d16</InvoiceGUID>
                 <UserGUID>4b43281a</UserGUID>
                 <WorkTypeGUID>31566f</WorkTypeGUID>
             </HourEntry>
              <HourEntry>
                 <CaseGUID>aaaaa</CaseGUID>
                 <GUID>bbbbbb</GUID>
                 <InvoiceGUID>ccccc</InvoiceGUID>
                 <UserGUID>ddddd</UserGUID>
                 <WorkTypeGUID>eeeee</WorkTypeGUID>
             </HourEntry>
           </Entries>
        <ExpectedHours>1</ExpectedHours>
        <TotalHours>4</TotalHours>
    </WorkDayInfo>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

This is my xsl file:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
            xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>
<xsl:variable name="delimiter" select="','"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <!-- Output the CSV header -->
    <xsl:text>Activ,Date,ExpectedHours,TotalHrs,CaseGUID,GUID,InvoiceGUID,UserGUID,WorkTypeGUID&#10;</xsl:text>
    <!-- Output the values -->
    <xsl:for-each select="//WorkDayInfo">
        <!-- begin values -->
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(Activities, $delimiter, Date, $delimiter,ExpectedHours,$delimiter,TotalHours)"/>     

        <!-- Category Values -->
        <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="Entries/HourEntry">
        <xsl:choose>           
        <xsl:when test="position()=0">        
            <xsl:value-of select="CaseGUID"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="GUID"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="InvoiceGUID"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="UserGUID"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="WorkTypeGUID"/>              
        </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:text>&#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(CaseGUID,'&#9;,',GUID,'&#9;,',InvoiceGUID,'&#9;,',UserGUID,'&#9;,',WorkTypeGUID,'&#10;')"/>           
        <!--<xsl:value-of select="concat(title, '&#9;', para, '&#10;')"/>-->
            <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
                <xsl:text></xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>          
        <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
            <xsl:text>&#9;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

This is the output(undesired) after processing:

```
     Activi,Date,ExpectedHours,TotalHrs,CaseGUID,GUID,InvoiceGUID,UserGUID,WorkTypeGUID
test1,12-01-12,9,10,    3fee9c7 ,kfsdsdlf   ,a2d169 ,4b4328 ,31566
            1111    ,2222   ,3333   ,4444   ,5555
test2,13-01-09,3,5, 3fee9c79c,kfsdsdl   ,a2d169c  ,4b43281  ,31566f
            3fee9c7s    ,kfsdsd4    ,a2d16s ,4b43281ab  ,31566s6
 test3,13-01-09,1,4,    
 test4,13-01-09,1,4, 3fee9c790  ,kfsdsdlfk  ,a2d16  ,4b43281a   ,31566f
            aaaaa   ,bbbbbb ,ccccc  ,ddddd  ,eeeee
```

But as you see in the above output,the second rows child element should have same row data (first 4 column). In the example shown below and this is the output(desired) I expect. I hope someone can throw some light where I am going wrong?

```
Activ,Date,ExpectedHours,TotalHours,CaseGUID,GUID,InvoiceGUID,UserGUID,WorkTypeGUID                               
test1,12-01-12,9,10,3fee9c7,kfsdsdlf,a2d169,4b4328,31566
test1,12-01-12,9,10,3fee9c7,aaaaa,bbbbbb,ccccc,ddddd,eeeee
....
test4,13-01-09,1,4,3fee9c790,kfsdsdlfk,a2d16,4b43281a,31566f
test4,13-01-09,1,4,aaaaa,bbbbbb,ccccc,ddddd,eeeee
```

Comment: Are you interested in converting `xml` to `csv` ? if yes, take a look at : http://www.csvreader.com/code/cs/xml_to_csv.php

Comment: @hdoghmen, hi there, i can already convert the from xml to csv. as you can see from the output. i just need some helpin formatting my xsl as it is not giving me the output i want.

Comment: Did you try to remove spaces : `string trimmed = yourResult.Replace(" ", string.Empty);` ?

Comment: No i havent, i dont know how to do it, as i said i am quite new xml.

Comment: @hdoghmen thanks mate, i can fix that but my problem next problem is the biggest, that is how to get this result:Activ,Date,ExpectedHours,TotalHours,CaseGUID,GUID,InvoiceGUID,UserGUID,WorkTypeGUID                               
test1,12-01-12,9,10,3fee9c7,kfsdsdlf,a2d169,4b4328,31566
test1,12-01-12,9,10,3fee9c7,aaaaa,bbbbbb,ccccc,ddddd,eeeee

Comment: How this output is different from the one before ?

Comment: @hdoghmen,before i go on, i must day that i appreciate you taking time to look at the problem. The second row is missing the parent values (see my desired output example above.)i want to child to have reference to parent values. first column is test1.....3fee9c7 as it has child element with the value 1111,2222,etc i would like this values to be linked to the parent value. i am also trying to solve this as http://xsltransform.net/gWmuiKs/7 .

Comment: The question is marked as a duplicate in vain. Question on the link how to delete extra spaces. Problem the author is how to make output parent nodes together with its descendants.

Answer (score 0):

If your prosessing is ok, add just a step to remove the spaces :

```
string undesired = @" Activi,Date,ExpectedHours,TotalHrs,CaseGUID,GUID,InvoiceGUID,UserGUID,WorkTypeGUID
test1,12-01-12,9,10,    3fee9c7 ,kfsdsdlf   ,a2d169 ,4b4328 ,31566
        1111    ,2222   ,3333   ,4444   ,5555
test2,13-01-09,3,5, 3fee9c79c,kfsdsdl   ,a2d169c  ,4b43281  ,31566f
        3fee9c7s    ,kfsdsd4    ,a2d16s ,4b43281ab  ,31566s6
test3,13-01-09,1,4,    
test4,13-01-09,1,4, 3fee9c790  ,kfsdsdlfk  ,a2d16  ,4b43281a   ,31566f
        aaaaa   ,bbbbbb ,ccccc  ,ddddd  ,eeeee";


string trimmed = undesired.Replace(" ", string.Empty);
Console.WriteLine(trimmed);
```

You will get this output :

```
Activi,Date,ExpectedHours,TotalHrs,CaseGUID,GUID,InvoiceGUID,UserGUID,WorkTypeGUID
test1,12-01-12,9,10,3fee9c7,kfsdsdlf,a2d169,4b4328,31566
1111,2222,3333,4444,5555
test2,13-01-09,3,5,3fee9c79c,kfsdsdl,a2d169c,4b43281,31566f
3fee9c7s,kfsdsd4,a2d16s,4b43281ab,31566s6
test3,13-01-09,1,4,
test4,13-01-09,1,4,3fee9c790,kfsdsdlfk,a2d16,4b43281a,31566f
aaaaa,bbbbbb,ccccc,ddddd,eeeee
```

Comment: thank you @jongware for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <!-- Output the CSV header -->
        <xsl:text>Activities,Date,CaseGUID,GUID</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>

        <!-- Output the values -->
        <xsl:for-each select="//WorkDayInfo">
            <xsl:variable name="head">
                <xsl:value-of select="concat(Activities,',',Date)"/>
            </xsl:variable>

            <xsl:for-each select="./Entries">
                <xsl:if test="count(*) = 0">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$head"/>
                    <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
                </xsl:if>

                <xsl:for-each select="./HourEntry">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$head"/>
                    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat(CaseGUID,',',GUID)"/>
                    <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:for-each>

        </xsl:for-each>

    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: thank you! this is what i was looking for!! One minor update to the request, i want  select only the few number of column, output only selected header for example caseGUID and UserGuid, how do i dot that?

Comment: @Niki - See update. I did a very simple example.

Comment: just wanted to say thank you for your help,